# IIS node watch file update automatically using babel cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, babeljs

I am using reactjs when call for server side rendering. I am using this code in web.config file.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="BABEL_CACHE_PATH" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

When I update data in any jsx or js file then not automatically update in the browser. I delete that cache file and regenerate it. but I don't do like this every time. how can I achieve without delete that file and automatic update browser?

Please help me.